# Schedule a SQL Server Migration Assistant every morning to happen automattically

Tags: sql, automation, migration, scheduled-tasks, data-migration

I have a a2ssproj that is run every morning that migrates MS Access data Tables into Microsoft SQL server Management Studio.  It usually take an hour and half.

I was wondering if there is a way to use a task scheduler to execute this every morning say at 5 am instead of having to manually double click Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant, choosing the recent project and clicking Ok to overwrite all.

I was thinking of doing this in C# or vb.net and just importing all the data and inserting it into sql.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Hi, were you able to figure out how to do it?

Comment: Actually yes I was.  First i ran this as a UIAutomation emulating a users click behavior which became daunting since sometimes the buttons wouldn't be in the exact same spot. I perfected but once i did we switched from Access completely to MSSQL server and i have this automated as a job.  Thanks for the reply.